# How do i pass the value of textarea which is stored in a variable into a div using the JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to update status but before posting it to server i want to use javascript to update a `div(globalfeed)`. I wrote the following code and it did not work the way i want it.

javascript code:

```
<script>

 function updateStatus(){

var textarea = $(".status").val();

 $("#globalfeed").prepend(textarea + '<div class="u_posted"><img height="40" width="40" src="uploaded/blank-profile.png"></div><div class="u_status"></div>');

     }

 </script>
```

html code:

```
<button type="button" name="status-btn" onClick="updateStatus()" class="status-btn">Post</button>
```

I want the value of textarea to appear inside the div `.u_status`.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I missing something?  If you want it to be inside `u_status`, then...just put it there?

```
function updateStatus(){

    var textarea = $(".status").val();

    $("#globalfeed").prepend('<div class="u_posted"><img height="40" width="40" src="uploaded/blank-profile.png"></div><div class="u_status">' + textarea  + '</div>');

}
```

Comment: thank you @Paul. I didn't know I can concatenate it that way. It was much helpful

Answer (score 0):

Assign it like this:

```
$(".u_status").html(textarea);
```